# Support for dynamic properties in DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, dynamic-properties

I have a simple DataGrid, that looks like this

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GridList}">
   <DataGrid.RowStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
         <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Grid>
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition />
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ID}" />
               </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But now I want to add another `TextBlock` in `DataTemplate` that looks like this

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Values["Entity1"]}" />
```

Or

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Values.Entity1}" />
```

But I cannot get it working, actually I do not know how to create the Last one so it is going to work

The model for the List looks like this

```
class ListModel {
   public int ID {get;set;}
   public IDictionary<string, string> Values {get;set;}
}
```

Of course I can replace the IDictionary to something else but what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I figured it out, I changed the ListModel to

```
class ListModel {
   public string this[string key] { get{return _values[key];} set{_values[key]=value;}}
   public int ID{get;set;}
   public IDictionary<string,string> _values = new Dictionary<string,string>();
}
```

And the XAML to

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding [Entity1]}" />
```